# How do I convert a one to many relationship to a flat array using mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

How can I format a one to many relationship to one 'row' using mysql or php?

**Main Table**

```
movie_id name
1        Portland
2        Blazers
```

**Many Table**

```
movie_id actor
1        Brandon
2        Greg
```

Below is the psudo code I have mapped out.  Not sure if there is any thing native to PHP or MYSQl that would be more efficient before I continue.  I'm thinking I have two queries.  One with the movie information.  One with the actor information.  Once they are arrays I will loop through to get a single record for each movie with the actors.

```
movieInfo = = []
actorInfo = = []

Foreach(movieActorId)
    If(actorId = movieActorId)
         arrayPush(movieInfo[actorArray],actorInfo[name]);
```

The final array would look like this

```
movieInfo = array('movie_id' => '1', 
                    'movie_name' => 'porland', 
                    'actor' => array(Brandon,Greg)
                    );
```

Comment: You don't want the actors' names in the final array?

Comment: My answer builds an array of movies, where each element is like the array you are looking for. If you need only one movie, just get rid of the `while` loop and the first array is what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you need:

```
SELECT m.movie_id, m.name AS movie_name, GROUP_CONCAT(a.actor SEPARATOR ',') AS actor
FROM movies m
JOIN actors a ON m.movie_id = a.movie_id
GROUP BY m.movie_id;

// Run query

$movieInfo = array();
while ($array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $array['actor'] = explode(',', $array['actor']);
    $movieInfo[] = $array;
}
```

Comment: I did not know about the Group_Concat.  Many Thanks!